# How configure a local package for use in a NestJS app?

Tags: nestjs, package.json

I cant import classes from a local package, please see summary below.

## NestJS app

I created a NestJS app called `exp1` with the cli:

```
nest new exp1
```

Then, add my local package

```
yarn add "file:../core"
```

Next, I want to import classes from the package. In `app.controller` I put

```
import { Feature } from '@me/core'
...
console.log(Feature)
```

So far so good, no warnings. But the `console.log()` output is `undefined`.

## Package configuration

#### package.json

```
{
    "name": "@me/core",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "src/index.d.ts",
    "files": [
        "/dist",
        "/src"
    ],
    ...
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,      
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,    
    "lib": ["es2019",],
    "target":"ES6"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

#### index.ts

```
export { Feature } from './Feature'
```

#### Feature.ts

```
export class Feature {
    public type = 'unknown'
}
```

#### webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.ts('src/index.ts', 'dist')
```

Running this successfully outputs `dist/index.js`, `src/index.d.ts`, `src/Feature.d.ts`

## Clues

The typing seems to work in `NestJS` app

```
(new Feature).type // OK
(new Feature).typo // Warning
```

However when accessing `Feature` it is always undefined..

Not sure what I am missing. Is it correct to point `package.json` main attribute to `dist/index.js` file or should it point to `index.ts`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(new Feature()).type`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel not necessarily since it does not have any arguments that is ok. Anyhow Feature is undefined

Comment: I don't see why the `Feature` would come in as `undefined`. You seem to be importing it correcctly, and it's the JS you're importing, so that should be fine. So long as the `../core` package is built, I'd expect it to be fine. Any chance you can share code?

Comment: Repos: https://github.com/data-story-org/node-server + https://github.com/data-story-org/core. Thanks for taking a look @JayMcDoniel

Comment: It looks like for whatever reason, the webpack config isn't allowing for the export from `index.ts`. It's _seeming_ like larvel-mix is specifically for creating a single file for running a  node process, not really for exporting features, but I can't say that for certain